# JScrollPane not showing up on inherited JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

I have a class which extends a JPanel. Code below:

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements Testnterface {
    private JScrollPane listScroller;

    DefaultListModel model;
    private JList requestList;    
    public Test() {

        String title = "Stackoverflow Question";
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        model = new DefaultListModel();
     requestList = new JList(); // create a list
        listScroller = new JScrollPane(requestList); // create a scrollbar to the list
        listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));

        setLayout(null);
        add(listScroller); // even though I add the scrollPane, nothing is displayed   
    }
 }
```

I updated the code. I can't seem to get my JScrollPane to be displayed on my JPanel even though I add it. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  This is almost certainly part of the problem.  I'll look further into it when you post an SSCCE.

Comment: setLayout(null) is used so I can customize the the components graphically using a design builder.

Comment: *"setLayout(null) is used so I can.."* ..break the GUI then come running to SO for help?  ***Use Layouts!***  As an aside, most 'design builders' worth using support layouts.

Comment: @TobiasJohansson : When you use `null` layout, you can not simply add straightforward. You need to specify it's location and size too explicitly. For that you can either use the respective function `setSize()/setLocation()` or you can simply use `setBounds(x, y, width, height)` to place your component on the screen. Though null layout is not a good idea for a many a reasons, avoid it as much as you can.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson, `setLayout(null)` might be a problem as well, but for me even using it with layout (SpringLayout in my case) resulted in JScrollPane to not be displayable. Possible workaround is to wrap around JPanel with empty border layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by wrapping scroll pane with JPanel:

```
final JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,
     JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
     JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE));
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE, 
      BORDER_SIZE, BORDER_SIZE));

panel.add(jScrollPane);
```